# Is it possible to contact a user directly?

Tags: support

I noticed that a user posted technical information unwillingly (too large a
screen capture).

I would like to contact him to inform of this potential leak.

A comment wouldn't be appropriate.

Is there a means to send a direct message to another user?

Comment: Why would a comment not be appropriate? Because it draws attention to the exposure, I assume?

Comment: Good guess unfortunatly.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can either comment or talk to him in a chatroom.
If you don't see him in any of the existing rooms, you can invite him for a "private" chat (note these chats are not really private, at all really).

If there is significant info exposure, the user can delete it and ask SE community team to redact it permanently...

Comment: Thank you for fixing the problem :).